# random string of numbers

Tags: java, arrays

I want to print a string of numbers, but I get the followyng: [I@7c230be4

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

class Aleatorio {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random diceRoller = new Random();
        int cifra[]= new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < cifra.length; i++) {
            int roll = diceRoller.nextInt(9)+1 ;
            cifra[i]=roll;
        }
        System.out.println(cifra);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should print every item in the array, not the array itself.

Comment: I want to print the array, because later i am going to compare it with a another array.

Comment: Integer array is **not** a String.

Comment: @Jaime you're printing the array, not its contents. In order to print the array contents, you should do it in a loop like `for-loop`: `for(int i = 0; i < cifra.length; i++) { System.out.println(cifra[i]); }`. Other person has proposed to use the enhanced for to do the job, it will work too.

Comment: Then do it in the same loop one array element at a time, like it has been already suggested by Luiggi Mendoza.

Comment: Even easier maybe for the wanted output: `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(cifra));`

Comment: Luiggi Mendoza you are right.

Answer (score 4):

You are seeing the `Object#toString` representation of the `int` array `Object`. To display its contents, you could use:

```
Arrays.toString(cifra)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for (int c : cifra) {
  System.out.println(c);
}
```

instead of this

```
System.out.println(cifra);
```